# python listen the windows log event

Tags: python, windows, events, logging

I readed example ,about use pywin32 to read windows event log :

[Python's win32 access for the Eventlog](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/Windows_NT_Eventlog.html)

now i wonder if i could take the next step :
Fire a python function (my code) ,once a windows event log has arrived(may be the log was set by  other application ), so i can monitor the event in real time .

i goole it the whole day, and can't find a good resolve.
that's my test code :

```
import win32evtlog
import win32event

def function_wait():
    #i check the new windows log is set , but this function wasn't fired
    print 'a new event log.' 

file_open_hand = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog('my-pc','Application')
# i thought it's definitly wrong below, but i have no idear about the 4th parameter!
hEvent = win32event.CreateEvent (None, 1, 0, 'function_wait') 

win32evtlog.NotifyChangeEventLog(file_open_hand,hEvent)

inputx = raw_input("wait for event log fire...")
```

Comment: You might have to do something like the code in this very old example that waits for [directory change notifications](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html#use_findfirstchange). The thing to note being how it sets up a change handle and then uses it with `win32event.WaitForSingleObject()`.

Comment: Thanks,martineau! Yes，i check the post before, the 3rd approache is good( by a blocking call ).
And what i need just a blocking call like :
`results = win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW (...)`
  
 maybe `win32evtlog.ReadEventLogChange(.....)` or sth. else.
 
OR
 `win32evtlog.NotifyChangeEventLog`
 was designed for that, just i wasn't properly understand it?
 doc is simple :
 [win32evtlog__NotifyChangeEventLog](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32evtlog__NotifyChangeEventLog_meth.html)

Comment: According to the documentation, if you want [`WaitForSingleObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to block, just pass it a time-out interval of `INFINITE` for its `dwMilliseconds` argument. The infinite time-out value is `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149692/how-to-have-a-feed-of-windows-log-event-under-windows/26149749#26149749