# How to have a feed of windows log event under windows?

Tags: python, pywin32

The problem was the following: have a feed of the event log under windows. I was asked on irc to help to solve it. I give as an answer the solution we reached.

I was inspired by this question [python listen the windows log event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254345/python-listen-the-windows-log-event)

Answer (score 2):

Solution

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import win32evtlog # requires pywin32 pre-installed
import win32event

server = 'localhost' # name of the target computer to get event logs
logtype = 'System' # 'Application' # 'Security'
filehandler = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(server,logtype)
eventhandler = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 1, 0, "wait")
flags = win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_FORWARDS_READ|win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEEK_READ
win32evtlog.NotifyChangeEventLog(filehandler, eventhandler)

cursorlog = win32evtlog.GetNumberOfEventLogRecords(filehandler)
cursorlog+=1
print("Go to : %s" % (cursorlog))        
while self.skip == False:

    #the timeout delay can be set to 0xFFFFFFF for infinite timeout
    result = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(eventhandler, 1)
    # Timeout
    if not result :

        readlog = win32evtlog.ReadEventLog(filehandler, flags, cursorlog)

        for event in readlog:
            print("%s : [%s] : %s" % (event.TimeGenerated.Format(), event.RecordNumber, event.SourceName))
        cursorlog+=len(readlog)
```